# Is PyCharm Community Edition doesn't have Database Tool?

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea, pycharm

I'm using pycharm 2020.3 community edition. but id doesn't showing database tool. it means this edition comes without that option? or any action we have to do for this?

*Note: some people saying add plugin data base browser. but that is not built in. I want database tool.

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm Community doesn't have database tools. See comparison matrix https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html